# Get highest value in row, but only under specific condition from previous rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe:

```
                        1     2     3
datetime                             
2021-01-23 00:01:00  10.0  11.0  15.0
2021-01-23 00:02:00  12.0  10.0   NaN
2021-01-23 00:03:00  16.0  12.0   NaN
```

(In reality, there are more columns like 1-3...)

I want to add two columns like this:

```
                        1     2     3  new_max  new_max_col
datetime                             
2021-01-23 00:01:00  10.0  11.0  15.0     15.0            3
2021-01-23 00:02:00  12.0  10.0   NaN      NaN          NaN
2021-01-23 00:03:00  16.0  12.0   NaN     16.0            1
```

**Actions needed:**

- Column `new_max`: Copy the highest value in the row to this column, but in case there is an NaN in this row, only if it is higher than the last value (from previous rows) before NaN. Otherwise set the value in `new_max` to NaN.
- Column `new_max_col`: Set to the name of the column where the `new_max` value was taken from.

**My problem:** If I would simply use `.fillna(method='ffill')` before comparison, I would get 15.0 in `new_max` for the second row, but this would be wrong. Only "new" high values should be copied to `new_max`, while values from `.fillna` should be used for comparison only.

Code to create the original dataframe:

```
import io, pandas as pd, numpy as np

t = io.StringIO("""
datetime|1|2|3
2021-01-23 00:01:00|10|11|15
2021-01-23 00:02:00|12|10|NaN
2021-01-23 00:03:00|16|12|NaN""")
df = pd.read_csv(t, sep='|', parse_dates=['datetime'], dtype=np.float64).set_index('datetime')
```

**!!! EDIT !!!**

Here is more and different testing data to describe the problem:

```
                        1     2     3
datetime                             
2021-01-23 00:00:00  20.0   NaN  15.0
2021-01-23 00:01:00  12.0   NaN   NaN
2021-01-23 00:02:00  10.0  17.0   NaN
2021-01-23 00:03:00   NaN  14.0  18.0
2021-01-23 00:04:00  16.0  12.0   NaN
```

Note that there could be more than 2 consecutive NaN in a column (not in this example).

Result should be:

```
                        1     2     3 new_max new_max_col
datetime                                                 
2021-01-23 00:00:00  20.0   NaN  15.0    20.0           1
2021-01-23 00:01:00  12.0   NaN   NaN     NaN         NaN
2021-01-23 00:02:00  10.0  17.0   NaN    17.0           2
2021-01-23 00:03:00   NaN  14.0  18.0    18.0           3
2021-01-23 00:04:00  16.0  12.0   NaN     NaN         NaN
```

**- Row 0:** 20 is the highest.

**- Row 1:** Compare 12 and 15 (15 is lookback from first row in column "3"). 15 is the highest, but it is not "new" (it comes from looking back to the last number before NaNs in the column), so the result is NaN.

**- Row 2:** Compare 10, 17, 15 (15 is lookback). 17 is the highest.

**- Row 3:** Compare 10 (lookback), 14, 18. 18 is the highest.

**- Row 4:** Compare 16, 12, 18 (lookback). 18 is the highest but it's from lookback, so result is NaN.

Code to generate new testing dataframe:

```
import io, pandas as pd, numpy as np

t = io.StringIO("""
datetime|1|2|3
2021-01-23 00:00:00| 20|NaN| 15
2021-01-23 00:01:00| 12|NaN|NaN
2021-01-23 00:02:00| 10| 17|NaN
2021-01-23 00:03:00|NaN| 14| 18
2021-01-23 00:04:00| 16| 12|NaN""")
df = pd.read_csv(t, sep='|', parse_dates=['datetime'], dtype=np.float64).set_index('datetime')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If first row has no missing values is possible compare by [`Series.cummax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummax.html) with rows with missing values and set to `NaN`s:

```
df1=df.agg(['max','idxmax'],axis=1).rename(columns={'idxmax':'max_col'}).add_prefix('new_')

mask = df1['new_max'].cummax().ne(df1['new_max']) & df.isna().any(axis=1)

df1 = df.join(df1.mask(mask))
print (df1)
                        1     2     3 new_max new_max_col
datetime                                                 
2021-01-23 00:01:00  10.0  11.0  15.0    15.0           3
2021-01-23 00:02:00  12.0  10.0   NaN     NaN         NaN
2021-01-23 00:03:00  16.0  12.0   NaN    16.0           1
```

EDIT:

```
#forward fill NaNs
df11 = df.ffill()
df1 = (df11.agg(['max','idxmax'],axis=1)
           .rename(columns={'idxmax':'max_col'})
           .add_prefix('new_'))

#comapre only ffill values by new_max
mask = df11.where(df.isna()).max(axis=1).eq(df1['new_max'])

df1 = df.join(df1.mask(mask))
print (df1)
                        1     2     3 new_max new_max_col
datetime                                                 
2021-01-23 00:00:00  20.0   NaN  15.0    20.0           1
2021-01-23 00:01:00  12.0   NaN   NaN     NaN         NaN
2021-01-23 00:02:00  10.0  17.0   NaN    17.0           2
2021-01-23 00:03:00   NaN  14.0  18.0    18.0           3
2021-01-23 00:04:00  16.0  12.0   NaN     NaN         NaN
```

EDIT1: If need also compare original max values add another mask:

```
print (df)
                        1     2     3
datetime                             
2021-01-23 00:00:00  20.0   NaN  15.0
2021-01-23 00:01:00  12.0   NaN   NaN
2021-01-23 00:02:00  10.0  17.0   NaN
2021-01-23 00:03:00   NaN  14.0  18.0
2021-01-23 00:04:00  18.0  12.0   NaN <- changed value to 18

#forward fill NaNs
df11 = df.ffill()
df1 = (df11.agg(['max','idxmax'],axis=1)
           .rename(columns={'idxmax':'max_col'})
           .add_prefix('new_'))

#compare only ffill values by new_max
mask = df11.where(df.isna()).max(axis=1).eq(df1['new_max'])
mask1 = df1['new_max'].ne(df.max(axis=1))
df1 = df.join(df1.mask(mask & mask1))
print (df1)
                        1     2     3 new_max new_max_col
datetime                                                 
2021-01-23 00:00:00  20.0   NaN  15.0    20.0           1
2021-01-23 00:01:00  12.0   NaN   NaN     NaN         NaN
2021-01-23 00:02:00  10.0  17.0   NaN    17.0           2
2021-01-23 00:03:00   NaN  14.0  18.0    18.0           3
2021-01-23 00:04:00  18.0  12.0   NaN    18.0           1
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I just found a problem with this solution.

Replace row 0 of the original df with this data: `2021-01-23 00:01:00|10|20|15`

Now in the last row, the value in `new_max` should be 16.0, but it is NaN.

How can I fix this?

Comment: @Mike - Not sure if understand, then first value is `20`, second NaN and last is not `NaN` because `16 < 20`

Comment: In the original sample data, only replace the 11 in the first row with 20. This 20 should not have any influence on the new_max result in the last row: It should be 16, because it would compare 16, 12 and 15. The 20 from the first row should not have any influence on the last row. Only when there are NaN in the previous rows of the same column, it should look back.

Comment: Last row: 16 is new, 12 is new, 15 is from looking back to the last entry before two NaN. 16 is the highest value in the row and it is "new" (does not come from looking back before NaNs), so 16 will go to new_max in the last row. Any value in columns "`1`" or "`2`" of the first row has no influence on this.

Comment: @Mike - is possible add more data in sample? Thanks.

Comment: @Mike - 10 rows if possible should be perfect.

Comment: Yes sure, I have added new data, see the original question **below "!!! EDIT !!!"**. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Thank you very much @jezrael, it looks perfect now! Sorry for initially providing insufficient data!